# How do I import a trained deep CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have trained a deep CNN model on GPU on a cluster using Tensorflow. Now I want to load that model in my laptop. But when I want to use the following command I receive an error:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./3/Model_Arch3/Deep_CNN_Color_Arch8.ckpt-178000.meta')
```

The error that I receive is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dev_test.py", line 28, in
>   
>       new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./3/Model_Arch3/Deep_CNN_Color_Arch8.ckpt-178000.meta')
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1810, in import_meta_graph
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py",
>   line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
>       producer_op_list=producer_op_list)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 285, in import_graph_def
>       raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op) ValueError: No op named ParseSingleExample in defined
>   operations.

I really appreciate if someone help me with this problem.

Comment: I have a feeling that maybe relative paths may not be supported. Can you try passing the full path of the file?

Comment: I tried passing the full path of the file but it did not work.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I train this network on my laptop using my CPU, then I can load the model without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the problem.
I was using python 3.5.4 for training procedure. Then I used python 2.7 for reconstructing the graph and that was the problem.
Thanks from those who tried to help

Comment: Ah just noticed this. Would you mind upvoting to show how we arrived at finding the right issue? May help others considering trying all the approaches we did since that issue can arise for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be a lazy loading issue with the operation you are trying to perform.
Try adding `dir(tf.contrib)` a line before you load your graph.

For reference — a similar issue was raised in an old TF GitHub issue 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10130

---

UPDATE:

I think I see the issue now. Since you trained on a GPU and youre running on a regular machine / CPU now. You need to clear the devices from the loaded object. Try adding clear_devices as a param:

```
dir(tf.contrib)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(full_file_path, clear_devices=True)
```

Lastly, your TF version between your local and GPU machine may be out of sync. Try to update your local version.

Comment: This problems happens when I get the graph from the code that I ran on my gpu.
But when I run this code on my laptop without GPU  and get the graph files it works fine.

Comment: I tried new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(full_file_path, clear_devices=True)
but it did not work too!

Comment: Hm, interesting. Can you try with my updated code? Make sure that this is where the error occurs, and other lines don't interfere. Ofc full_file_path should be the file path of the file of interest :)

Comment: I tried your code but still does not work!
I removed the other unnecessary lines of code

Comment: I can build the graph on the GPU cluster where I trained my model.

Comment: Hm. I might be wrong here, but are you loading the right file? As far as I remember checkpoint files ('ckpt') are different than model graph files.

Comment: These are the files that I use
Deep_CNN_Color_Arch3.ckpt-359000.meta
Deep_CNN_Color_Arch3.ckpt-359000.index
Deep_CNN_Color_Arch3.ckpt-359000.data-00000-of-00001

Comment: Can you compare the TF versions between your GPU machine and local machine? Might have to update your local one.

Comment: python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3

Comment: on my laptop tensorflow version was 1.4.1
when I installed python 3, I installed tensorflow version 1.11

Comment: OK. Please try to synchronize your TF version to match up with your GPU machine version, and let me know how it goes. I think that s/b a quick way to arrive at a resolution (supposing we found the issue that is).